# how to update parameters defined in controller inside a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-promise

im using angular and typescript for a single page app
I need to update the controller's parameter value (_isShowFirst) but it seems to be that inside the promise nothing is recognized.
my service function returns a Promise
This is my controller:

```
module CreditCardActivation {
    'usestrict';

export class CreditCardActivationController {

    public _isShowFirstStep: boolean;
    public _isShowSecondStep: boolean;
    public _errorMessage: string;


    constructor() {
        this._isShowFirstStep = true;
        this._isShowSecondStep = false;
    }



    activate = () => {

        this.ActivationService.activate(somedata).then((result) => {
          //-------Problem is here ----------//
    this._isShowFirst = true
        });


    }
}
angular.module('Activation').controller('ActivationController', ActivationController)
```

}

This is my service activation function:

```
activate = (data:ActivationRequest): ng.IPromise<ActivationResponse> =>{
  var response = this.httpService.get("someurl").then({
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
});
return (response);
}
```

any idea?
thanks

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));` feels redundant

Comment: @basarat it doesnt affect my problem. again, i need to modify the controller parameters inside the promise (then..)

Comment: Yeah ... this was just a code comment, hence not put in answer :)

Comment: any idea about the answer ? :)

Answer (score 0):

> this.ActivationService.activate(somedata)

I don't see `ActivationService` being *injected* into the controller. I suspect you are getting an `undefined` error on the console.

Comment: I removed it just for the sake of the example. i do inject it,: constructor(activationService: IActivationServic).
The data also is retrieved correctly. the problem remains modifying the controller params

Comment: If you `console.log(this._isShowFirst)` what happens?

Comment: Presumably it is because the scope is wrong. Try to copy "this" to a local "self" variable and use it instead. `activate = () => {
            var self = this;

            this.ActivationService.activate(somedata).then((result) => {
                self._isShowFirst = true
            });
        }`